# Dart auto casting to most recent type?

Tags: flutter, dart

Why `myImageProvider` has the type of Object, but not ImageProvider.

I know I can use `if-else` clause, just curious about how auto-casting works.

```
final myImageProvider = (debugAssetPath != null)
        ? AssetImage(debugAssetPath!)
        : FileImage(File(capturedImagePath));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart seems to have trouble resolving the generic `ImageProvider<T>`. As it cannot find a common base type it resolves to the base type of all dart objects - Object.

To fix it simply cast AssetImage to ImageProvider

```dart
final myImageProvider = (debugAssetPath != null)
        ? AssetImage(debugAssetPath!) as ImageProvider
        : FileImage(File(capturedImagePath));
```

The resulting myImageProvider will be of type `ImageProvider<Object>`, so you loose type safety for any subsequent calls to the methods of  myImageProvider with regards to the key property.

Comment: thank you, so it's the problem with generic, right? Loose type generic is my intent, so I don't concern it.

Answer (score 1):

Because Object is a root of the non-nullable Dart class hierarchy, every other `non-Null` Dart class is a subclass of Object.

Since in AssetImage and FileImage are a subclass of `Object` and its conditionally switch so for both Widget i.e class are commonly denote as Object.

Ref: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Object-class.html

Comment: hi, thank you, but felix provide an answer, so I will mark his answer as the solution.